# Python: Parsing Word document Table and Save CSV file

Tags: python, csv, ms-word

I would like to save some tables in word document to CSV file or Excel doesn't matter.
I tried to "readlines()" it doesn't work! I don't know know.

Tables in word document are like this..

```
Name Age Gender
Alex  12  F
Willy 14 M
.
.
.
```

However, I would like to save this table in the same row.. I mean that.. I would like to save in CSV or Excel File

```
Alex 12 F Willy 14 M ....
```

```
 import win32com
 word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
 f=word.Documents.Open('C:/3.doc')
```

Answer (score 2):

have a look to [www.ironpython.com](http://www.ironpython.com): it runs over .NET so it has all the libraries to access to the Microsoft world.
For your case, read this small tutorial about convert a ***.doc*** to a ***.txt*** file. It should be very useful for you:

http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Converting_a_Word_document_to_Text